can not put value on edit field with send_keys
My below XPATH is correct but can not put password value in password field. looks like send_keys mathod not working here. Anyone can help?
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//input[@name='password']")[0].send_keys('awE1100')
i am expected to put value on password field with my syntex

Try this:
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']").send_keys('awE1100')


Thank you, i also tried this earlier but did not work, i am getting below error:                        "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable"

after putting wait time (time.sleep(5)), it is working now. Thank you anyways
